# How get x:name of element in code behind / XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some images in **.xaml** like below:

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="image1.png">
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

<Image x:Name="image2" Source="image2.png">
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

when clicked, images call some action. Now in **xaml.cs** file I need get which image was clicked for use in **switch**:

```
    async void OnTapGestureTap(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        switch () //--HOW VERIFY IN SWiTCH WHICH IMAGE WAS CLICKED???
        {
            case image1:
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image1Page());
                break;
            case image2:
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image2Page());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could retrieve the original image name and switch on that string:

```
if (sender is Image image)
{
    switch (image.Source as FileImageSource).File) 
    {
        case "image1.png":
            Console.WriteLine("image1.png");
            break;
        case "image2.png":
            Console.WriteLine("image2.png");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this looks legit +1

Comment: Work great: switch (image.Source as FileImageSource) without .File in end.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have your heart set on a switch, this might work. The assumption is sender is actually an `Image` and the name will be the `x:Name`

**Update**

Try comparing sender with the image itself

```
 if(sender == image1)
      ...
```

**Original**

```
async void OnTapGestureTap(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   if(sender is Image image)
   {
      switch (image.Name) // switch on the name
      {
         case "image1":
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image1Page());
            break;
         case "image2":
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image2Page());
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

***Note*** : This is totally untested

Comment: `x:Name` generates a source code variable name, there is no `Name` property

Comment: This was a good try but image.Name (name not exist), I try with image.Id.toString() but the return is something like: "ea3719f9-9892-4b66-8225-e0662f379599"

Comment: mayebe `switch (nameof(image))` ?

Comment: @Conceptdev yeah thats not a bad idea, though i cant test it atm

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ClassId* property from Image

```
<Image ClassId="image1" Source="image1.png">
   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
   </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

<Image ClassId="image2" Source="image2.png">
   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
   </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

And in background just switch over *ClassId*

```
async void OnTapGestureTap(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    switch (image.ClassId)
    {
        case "image1":
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image1Page());
            break;
        case "image2":
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image2Page());
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats image.ClassId return?

Comment: It's a string property

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 async void OnTapGestureTap(object sender, EventArgs args)
{ 
  var image = sender as Image;

    switch (image) 
    {
        case image1:
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image1Page());
            break;
        case image2:
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image2Page());
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that `StyleID` is not specified then this property inherits the `x:Name` value as a string.

`x:Name` is the name of field generated by XAML. In this case the valid answer is

```
if (sender == image1)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image1Page());
}
else if (sender == image2) 
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Image2Page());
}
```

you can get the name of field underlined with the error message:

> The name 'image1' does not exist in current context.

but the context will be created when XAML loads it.